# Smooth image zoom on Double Tap

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I have an ImageView which I want to smoothly zoom on double tap.

Currently I have zoom working like this

```
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViewId);
         int width = imageView.getWidth();
         int height = imageView.getWidth();
         float maxScale;
         if ( width < height ) {
         maxScale = (float) (width * Math.pow(1.5, 6));
         } else {
         maxScale = (float) (height * Math.pow(1.5, 6));
         }

         Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
         int imageWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
         int imageHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
         float[] value = new float[9];
         matrix.getValues(value);
         scaleWidth = (int)(imageWidth * value[Matrix.MSCALE_X]);
         scaleHeight = (int)(imageHeight * value[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);

         if ( (scaleWidth * 2) < maxScale ) {
         matrix.postScale(2, 2, e.getRawX(), e.getRawY());
         } else {
         matrix.postScale(0, 0, e.getRawX(), e.getRawY());
         }
         isDoubleTab = true;
         tuneMatrix(matrix);
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        return false;
    }
```

It's not smooth at all. I googled a lot, but wasn't able to find any working solution for DoubleTap.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good link for imageZoom on double tap...
http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need, but unfortunately my app is 2.1, and realisation there relies on 2.2 (ScaleGestureDetector). This makes me sad.

Comment: At the end I decided to stick with 2.2.

Comment: good.. 2.1 is out of date . 2.2 has 64.6% share in current distribution...http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: You can back-port the ScaleGestureDetector that is part of 2.2 and use it on 2.1 (earlier versions didn't support multi-touch). You should make sure of using your back-ported class only on platforms that do not have it built-in, since newer platforms have issues with the 2.2 implementation.

Comment: where is easing and cubing classes in this library